# Why is Firebase Firestore with Swift 5.5 Toolchain generating an error?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I am running Xcode 13.0 with the Swift 5.5 toolchain.

When I load the pod 'Firebase/Firestore' and try to build, I get the following error:

> Missing '#include <stdlib.h>'; 'abort' must be declared before it is
> used

A screenshot of the code that is being highlighted below:

Note, that I have stripped this back so that I have zero code in my project - only the default that is provided with a new project.

[image: Screenshot of error and source code from Firebase Library]

Note, that I have stripped this back so that I have zero code in my project - only the default that is provided with a new project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update to a recent version of Firebase. The issue was fixed in March in https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/7552

Comment: Thank you Paul. It worked. One point if I may, this solution applies for those developers using the SPD method, however when you import the library using CocoaPods, the compile error still occurs (even after updating to the latest version of the SDK using 'pod update'. I imagine a lot of developers are still using CocoaPods, so a watch out for them, that they will have to move to SPD through Xcode if they want to use Firestore with the new Swift Toolchain, to take advantage of async/await and other new features.

Comment: Good point! However, we haven't seen the issue in our CocoaPods testing yet. I haven't investigated why.  What version of Xcode do you see it in?

Comment: It happened to me in 12.5 then I updated to 13.0, and still the same issue. Happy to share more information if needed!

Comment: Hmm. I haven't seen it, except when configuring the toolchain with `Preferences > Components > Toolchains`.  Are you doing that?

Comment: If I remember rightly, that is the way I installed the toolchain, yes. Per Peter Friese article here: https://peterfriese.dev/async-await-in-swiftui/

Comment: That explains it. That issue does not exist in the official Swift 5.5 that is built into Xcode 13.